# Manage song metadata on CentOS from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, media, metadata, mplayer

I am making a simple Pandora.com alternative for myself and a few friends where the user can upload his/her songs and listen to them anywhere. My intent is to make a lightweight, simple player in HTML5 so all the user needs is a current Firefox or Chrome to use it. I have set it up so that all uploaded songs get converted to .ogg and added to a database but I also want some metadata (not sure if that is the correct term) for the songs to be stored in the database so the player can tell the user what song he/she is listening too. I know there are several GUI tools for managing the title/artist/album info for songs but I'm having trouble finding any good ones I can use from the command line. If the song has the information already in the file, I think I can use mplayer to retrieve the information but it would be really great if there was one that would look up the song information online. I don't mind interfacing with an API (would be pretty interesting actually). Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i in.ogg -metadata title="my title" out.ogg
```

`-metadata key=value'

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html

Comment: ffmpeg works great for setting the metadata but it has no way to show the metadata. I ended up using pytags for my MP3s and `mplayer [filename] -ao /dev/null` for my WMAs.

Comment: @jamesbtate `ffmpeg` should ship with the `ffprobe` command which among other things shows the metadata. It writes its output to stderr and only accepts one file at a time, so it's kind of awkward to work with, but it can be done; see e.g. [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dmoles/ee97312c61bd6f4ee508c8b82ef0ffce).